# Route sudmains controller with Zend

Tags: zend-framework, subdomain, routes, zend-route

I have the following structure on my app:

Modules =>

```
            default => site.com
            blog => blog.site.com
            admin => admin.site.com
```

I used this code on my bootstrap to allow subdomains and redirect to the follow module:

```
$pathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':controller/:action/*', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();



    $blogDomainRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
            'blog.site.com', array(
        'module' => 'blog',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));

    $router->addRoute('blogdomain', $blogDomainRoute->chain($pathRoute));
```

And the same code to adminDomainRoute.

It works fine! But now i notice that my pagination route don't work, i have the follow route to manage pages in admin module:

```
routes.usuarios.route = /usuarios/pagina/:pagina
routes.usuarios.defaults.module = admin
routes.usuarios.defaults.controller = usuarios
routes.usuarios.defaults.action = index
routes.usuarios.defaults.pagina = 1
```

I tried to change the route to

```
routes.usuarios.route = admin.site.com/usuarios/pagina/:pagina
```

But i still got action no found:

array (
      'controller' => 'usuarios',
      'action' => 'pagina',
      'module' => 'admin',
   )

How can i route admin.site.com/usuarios/pagina/1 admin.site.com/usuarios/pagina/3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that jumps at me from your setup is, that in the `ini` format (your current admin route), you are using the default router. Well this router knows **nothing** about the hostname you are on, so it is looking for an url like this one:

```
site.com/admin.site.com/usuarios/pagina/1 admin.site.com/usuarios/pagina/3
```

What you want is something like this:

```
//Create a hostname route. This route is only concerned with the subdomain part of the uri
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    'admin.:host.:domain');
//Create a default router that would take care of the rest of the routing.
$defaultRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/usuarios/pagina/:pagina',
    array(
        'module'=>'admin',
        'controller'=>'usuarios',
        'action'=>'index'
    )
);
//Chain those two routes together to make them go one after the other. 
$defaultRoute=$hostnameRoute->chain($defaultRoute);
```

This code may need a bit of tweaking, but I think this should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you! Worked very nice, every subdomain route i'll need to create like this, right?

Comment: There is no quick way to do this. It could be done with a custom routing class.